# UML representation of your project

Tags: c#

Is there a way to basically get a nice UML or some kind of diagram that shows all of your objects and its members in a nice diagram for you?  Some tools out there?  I don't really know what to call this but that's what I am aiming to do instead of having to look at each class in VS all the time going back and fourth when planning out some new architecture based on existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio has a "Class Diagram" feature which can be used to create reasonably pretty pictures. It's pretty simple to use - I rather like it.

Comment: Visio extends this a bit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947873(VS.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you, that was the phrase I was looking for "class diagrams"

Comment: Interesting about Visio.  I recently though moved to EA.  But willing to check it out in VS also or even Visio.  It will be interesting to see how complex each ends up being in terms of readability

Comment: I've always found Visio incredibly painful to use. But then again, I don't want detailed technical bits - just something to give me a quick impression of how things fit together.

Comment: Yea, used to be a Visio fan but once I took a look at EA, it blew my mind away.  Far easier to use once you get used to the huge amount of options in EA

Comment: Nice VS 2010, forgot about all those models you can build!

Answer (score -1):

Enterprise Architect is my tool of choice for all things UML.

http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/8/index.html